# How do I post App version with JS electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I want to post the version of my app but instead I got this weird error. Does someone see what's wrong, because I can't see it. (Node.js is included)

error: Unexpected token <

```
<script>
  console.log(process);
   let output =
  <h2 class="page-header">App version Data</h2> 
   <ul class="list-group"> 
    <li class="list-group-item">Node: ${process.versions.node}</li>
     </ul>

   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
</script>
```

Comment: Right now you are showing your node version instead of app version

Comment: Are you missing backticks, I'm not seeing where the string starts/ends? Also, what is the `-->` doing in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your client-side Javascript, you could require `remote` to obtain the version of your application:

```
var appVersion = require("electron").remote.app.getVersion();
```

> remote (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)
>
> > Use main process modules from the renderer process.

[Example](https://github.com/1nv1n/review-dashboard/blob/master/src/js/renderer/infoModal.js#L30) of how I'm using it to determine app version.

Comment: `remote` no longer exists as of Electron 14. If you want to go down this route, you'll need to use https://github.com/electron/remote, though it's not without its issues (https://nornagon.medium.com/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31)

Answer (score 0):

`process.versions.node` is only available in Nodejs. Here you are trying to get the version number from a client side JavaScript(I assume..) which will not work.

You could expose a nodeJs api and write a Get request to get the vetsion in front end.

The electron have the following API for getting the app version, which gets the version from package.json.
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetversion

Comment: Node.js is included so that I have the ability to see the version of Node